# Why h2 and h4 tags does not change coloк in hover state?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to change the text color of my both links while hovering them over, but the color does not change? What is the reason?

```css
h2 {
color: green;
}

h4 {
color: pink;
}

a:hover {
color: lightblue;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">
    <h2>This is a header</h2>
    <h4>This is another header</h4>
</a>
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example in this question. Thanks

Comment: Your selector needs to be more specific `a:hover h2, a:hover h4 { ... }`

Comment: @Turnip —Specificity is not relevant. Targeting the correct element is.

Comment: Off topic, but I wonder how an r could turn into a к as a typo. I could understand if it had become a р or something.

Answer (score 2):

An element is whatever colour the element is.

By *default* the color of a heading is `inherit` so it takes on the colour of its parent element.

```css
div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  The div is blue
  <h1>The h1 is blue</h1>
</div>

<h1>The h1 is black</h1>
```

But if you set it explicitly, then it is whatever colour you set it to be…

```css
div {
  color: blue;
}

h1 {
  color: pink
}
```

```html
<div>
  The div is blue
  <h1>The h1 is pink</h1>
</div>

<h1>The h1 is pink</h1>
```

You are setting the `a` to `lightblue`, but since the headings are not `color: inherit` they aren't inheriting it. The `:hover` is irrelevant.

Write a selector that targets the headings (e.g. `a:hover h2, a:hover h4 { … }`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below, select all the elements inside anchor with *, see below.

```css
h2 {
color: green;
}

h4 {
color: pink;
}

a:hover * {
color: lightblue;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">
    <h2>This is a header</h2>
    <h4>This is another header</h4>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, is very simple :

```
h2:hover{
        color: lightblue;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
a:hover h2,
a:hover h4 {
    color: lightblue;
}
```

Try this!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like some of the inline styles (strong) may outweigh the css hover.  The example below puts the strong style in the CSS doc with span.  I also included the other two elements in the hover instruction.

HTML
`<a href="#">`
   `<p>This is a paragraph</p>enter code here`
    `<span>This is strong</span>`
    `</a>`
CSS
   `p {color: green;}`

```
`span {color: pink;`
`font-weight: bold}`

`a:hover, p:hover, span:hover  {color: lightblue;}`

`a {text-decoration: none; color: black;}`
```